# CMD batch file generated by vb.net app returns an unexpected error

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

Hello i have an application that generates cmd batch files (*.bat) and the executes them. After generation the file is as follows:

```
@echo off

echo AppNameAppVersion

echo (c) Company Name

echo y| cacls [FILE PATH] /G everyone:F>>C:\log.txt
```

When it executes I get an "System could find the file specified" error but what is weird is when I copy the file content into a CMD window it works like a charm! Why is this happening.

Comment: It seems like a relative-paths problem. To make sure re-do the tests with the full paths (e.g., "C\myfolder\myfile.txt")

Comment: no its not! The path contains the double-quotes. I mean it is in exactly the format it should be. The exact path is: "C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SSFW\bin\debug\log.text"

Comment: Sorry for not having made that clear but yet my problem is still :(

Comment: Yes, you have to wait for you someone with more experience in batch files (perhaps you should add some tags about this). Mine was just a generic help which I helped just in case of being applicable here.

Comment: You are welcome but you didn't add the tags. I have done it for you now.

Comment: I've found the culprit. Cmd interpretes my command As follows:
"echo y  |cacls [FILE PATH] >> 1 C:\log.txt"

note the extra space between "y" and "|" and the "1" before the log path. I wonder is all this happening.

Comment: If you feel that you have found something worthy to be shared you should write it as an answer. Other than that I cannot help you further; as said, I am not too experienced in batch-files/commands, what this question is about more than about VB.NET. Just wait for someone with some knowledge on this matter who might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've found it. I guess the log path was too long for cmd so I have created a new environment variable called "log" with the log file path. The command now is as such "echo y| cacls [File Path] /G everyone:F>>%log%"